# Div Scroll on MouseOver

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have a page http://armenianmusicawards.ru/gallery where I have horizontal image lists.

What jQuery plugin I can use for horizontal div scrolling on mouse over?

Each row scrolls separately. I tried http://www.maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/ , but there is problem, first time scrolls and second time disapears scrollers and nothing happens on mouse over.

What you can suggest? Any other plugins?

Edit: please look at my example to see what I need.

Comment: Like this? http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image_list").hover(function(){
        $("#image_list").css('overflow', 'scroll');
    });
});
```

hope it works